# How to Display Wordpress plugin on wordpress member side?

Tags: wordpress

i am making a simple WordPress-plugin . its showing setting page on admin side but i want it to display on member side . i have tried some tutorial,searched the internet and word press site also but didn't get it work.Basically i need a plugin where user can enter their cpanel detail and it got saved in user area then perform some Cpanel API.i can handle all this just need info how we can show plugin setting page on user side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it using 
$role=get_role('subscriber')
then adding cap to subscriber using
$role->add_cap

now i have to check if i can save settings for each user separately or it will get overwritten?

any help will be much appreciated